# How can I do this in a smarter way without conflict?

Tags: java, regex, split, automaton

In this way, it is returning some errors and it seems that the main examples are the characters of 2 characters, eg "++" being replaced by "# ++ #" while being close to replacing All () "to" ## + ## + ## ".

```
return lexeme.replaceAll(
        "==", "#==#"
    ).replaceAll(
        "&&", "#&&#"
    ).replaceAll(
        "=", "#=#"
    ).replaceAll(
        ">", "#>#"
    ).replaceAll(
        "++", "#++#"
    ).replaceAll(
        "<=", "#<=#"
    ).replaceAll(
        "!", "#!#"
    ).replaceAll(
        "-", "#-#"
    ).replaceAll(
        "--", "#--#"
    ).replaceAll(
        "+", "#+#"
    ).replaceAll(
        "+=", "#+=#"
    ).replaceAll(
        "*", "#*#"
    ).replaceAll(
        ",", "#,#"
    ).replaceAll(
        ".", "#.#"
    ).replaceAll(
        "[", "#[#"
    ).replaceAll(
        "{", "#{#"
    ).replaceAll(
        "(", "#(#"
    ).replaceAll(
        ")", "#)#"
    ).replaceAll(
        "}", "#}#"
    ).replaceAll(
        "]", "#]#"
    ).split( "#");
}
```

Comment: The complexity of this function is O(k(n)) where k is the number of replacements to be done. You can do this in O(n) but you have to override this method or define a new function and check the string word by word and replace it if a match is found in any of the above conditions.

Comment: You can do it with a single `replaceAll` call, using `$1` backreference in the replacement string: `return lexeme.replaceAll("(==?|&&|\\+[+=]?|<=|--?|[>!*,.\\[{()}\\]])", "#$1#").split("#");`

Comment: Thanks so much, but i need to know if there are any way without problem, because the way that I wrote is returning some problems.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas! I will try this way!

Comment: @Andreas , I still have problem with the following exemple: "++k". With this lexeme the split method isn't returning any string array. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: And @Andreas , for the ";" character, only this case was work for split: ");". The other cases as: 45; isn't working.

Comment: can you show use some input and expected outputs please?

Comment: @IgorNunes Your code doesn't have a `;`, so don't know what you're referring to. As for `"++k"`, with the code I gave, I get `[, ++, k]` as the result, so it works fine (`"++k"` becomes `"#++#k"` which splits to `["", "++", "k"]`).

Answer (score 1):

The main correctness issue is perhaps that you're calling `replaceAll()` on a result of previous replacement, so for example `==` gets first replaced to `#==#` due to the rule that targets `==` and then to `##=##=##` due to the replacement that targets `=`.

Also, your approach does not ensure that the longest matching target/needle is selected, so `+=` gets replaced to `+#=#` and then to `#+##=#` before it even reaches the `+=` target.